# Problem installing OpenNI

Tags: openni, ros-groovy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,

I have an Asus Xtion Pro Live and I wanted to install it for use with ROS. Not sure if it's relevant but I'm running Groovy connected to a Kobuki.

So when I run the install for the openni packages I get the below error.

```
sudo apt-get install -f ros-groovy-openni-camera ros-groovy-openni-launch
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ros-groovy-openni-camera : Depends: libboost-thread1.46.1 (>= 1.46.1-1) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Seeing that it depends on libboost-thread1.46.1 I tried to install libboost (boost_1_53_0) with the thread library option and the ran .g2 but still no joy. Am I missing something?

All I want to do is play around with the Xtion Pro Live and see what my robot sees!

Cheers,

Adrian.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61442/problem-installing-openni/) by [Praetorian](https://answers.ros.org/users/4747/praetorian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Praetorian](https://answers.ros.org/users/4747/praetorian/) on 2013-04-23**:
Should also add that I'm running Xubuntu 12.10 for the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You could try openni2 camera, it has quite a few bug fixes. Or maybe open up Software Centre and check that all the repositories are enabled.

---

Originally posted by [Jman](https://answers.ros.org/users/11456/jman/) with karma: 31 on 2014-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0